nvidia-smi shows "no devices were found" on windows server 2022 hyper-V ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine
I started a virtual machine on a Windows Server 2022 computer with an existing .vhdx file and successfully mounted an NVIDIA V100 32GB GPU. The file contains a mirror of a Ubuntu 22.04 environment with Nvidia driver version 535.183.01 installed. The mirror was built from an actual SSD and can respond to nvidia-smi with a table of GPU usage information. But things changed in the Hyper-V virtual machine. Never mind I'll show you the screenshot of what I have tried.
things that I tried and their responses
Some of the commands show that I've tried several methods but none of them solved the problem. Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the info into the question. This makes it easier to read and search as well as anyone trying to help does not have to switch screens to read the info.
